# MySQL syntax error Values

Tags: mysql, insert

I keep getting this error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'`contact` VALUES (0, 'Chris', 'rember', 'chris@fox.com')' at line 1
```

for the following code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contact;

CREATE TABLE contact (
  contactID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR (50),
  company VARCHAR (30),
  email VARCHAR (50)
);

INSERT INFO contact VALUES
  (0, 'Chris', 'rember', 'chris@fox.com');

SELECT * FROM contact;
```

This is very much my first database so I'm dead confused, I tried putting back ticks around contact, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

any clues?

Comment: Try again with `INSERT INTO` :-)

Comment: voted up ... nice one :)

Comment: 99% of the time, a syntax error is in the previous line or the previous word of where the error message points to. `INFO` is just before `contact` in that piece of code :)

Comment: (Side note, +1 for a clear and concise question. Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 3):

You wrote "INFO" instead of "INTO".  It should read:

```
INSERT INTO contact VALUES (0, 'Chris', 'rember', 'chris@fox.com');
```

Comment: Dam you dyslexia. THanks guys, I knew it would be something stupid.

Answer (score 3):

Small syntax error.

```
INSERT INFO contact VALUES
         ^
```

Should be

```
INSERT INTO contact VALUES
```